# postfix fatal: specify a password table via the `smtp_sasl_password_maps' configuration parameter

Tags: postfix

I'm using webmin and postfix to send emails, and I can't send emails,
I checked the logs in the file: `/var/log/maillog` anf found the following error:

```
fatal: specify a password table via the `smtp_sasl_password_maps' configuration parameter
```

how can I fix that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After sone googling I found the solution which was typo (made by postfix or webmin) `smtp_sasl_password_maps` which should have been `smtpd_sasl_password_maps` hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 9):

Came across the same thing while we were beefing up our security. We used Webmin to track changes. On the "SMTP Authentication And Encryption" page, the "Use SASL SMTP authentication?" option when 'Yes' is selected inserts `smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes` and it should be `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes`. You will need to manually edit the main.cf file, either via the Webmin interface or cli.

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to say :)